After upgrading to 24.10, booting results into a black screen in a loop (with a cursor)
After upgrading from 24.04 to 24.10, the boot stucks in a loop, just before the login screen. I can move the mouse on the black screen, but the page is refreshing every few seconds, showing a blinking cursor at the top of the screen.
When Ubuntu is loading, there is an error message:
ee1004 3-0050: probe with driver ee1004 failed with error -5

I'm using kernel 6.11.0-12-generic and my video card is a Radeon RX 580.
I have tried the following:

Updated the BIOS of my Asus TUF GAMING B550-PLUS.
Added nomodeset in GRUB.
Tried to use the older kernel 6.8.0-50-generic.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Please remove "Solved" from the title and the solution from the question and post it as an answer that you can later mark as the solution. Thanks!

Since you hadn't responded to my request, I took the liberty to edit your question and moved the solution to a Community Wiki answer (CW). As a CW, I won't get any points for it from potential upvotes. If you want to post the answer yourself, feel free to do so and I will delete the CW. Thanks!


After changing lightdm to gdm3 and reboot, I managed to login normally with the gdm login interface.
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3


Answer moved here from OP's question.
